# Linear Ehresmann connection on a vector bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, connections

[This article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehresmann_connection#Vector_bundles_and_covariant_derivatives) says that for an Ehresmann connection $H \subseteq TE$ of a vector bundle $E \to M$ to be linear (and so to define a connection in the usual sense as a linear covariant derivative operator) all you need is

$$D(S_\lambda)_e(H_e) = H_{\lambda e}$$
for $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ and $e \in E$, where $S_\lambda : E \to E$ is the multiplication by $\lambda$ map. But to me it seems like we also need $$D\sigma_{(e,e')} (H_e \oplus H_e') = H_{e + e'}$$
where $\sigma : E \oplus E \to E$ is the addition map and $e,e'$ lie on the same fiber. Can this somehow be deduced from the previous property, or is the claim in the article mistaken?

Comment: It sure looks like you're correct. We certainly need the sum of parallel sections to be parallel.

Comment: Actually it seems that the second property can indeed be deduced from the first, by the argument in this answer to what was basically the same question here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2659492/9921

Comment: More specifically, the first property is enough to show (via the usual Leibniz rule trick) that the covariant derivative of a section at a point only depends on the 1-jet of that section, and that this map $(J^1 E)_p \to E_p$ given by covariant derivative along a fixed $X$ is homogeneous; by the argument in that answer it is linear, which is equivalent to the second property.